# Trying to use old desktop tower as server for mongodb, but cant resolve a public IP

Tags: ip, mongodb

I am trying to bind to my public IP. However when editing the contents in `nano /etc/mongod.conf` It does not work. Now I think this might be the issue. Running `ifconfig` only shows my private ip address:

`enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255`

Now, I certinaly don't want to bind to this private ip address if I want to access this database from outside of my network, so how do I go about using my public ip address?

`# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,public_ip_here`

When trying to restart the service with this configuration, this is the error message I get:

```
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-06-15 19:04:21 EDT; 1s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 4616 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 4616 (code=exited, status=48)

Jun 15 19:04:21 server systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Jun 15 19:04:21 server systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=48/n/a
Jun 15 19:04:21 server systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm thinking the issue has to revolve around the fact that my public ip address is not being displayed upon executing the `ifconfig` command. However, I am not entirely sure. I am using an old desktop tower of mine with ubuntu on it to host the mongodb instance, in addition to the internet connection being wired. Thank you to all of those who reply in advance.

Comment: You bind the port to your 10. address and then forward the port from your router w/ public IP to the internal address.   For security, you may consider setting up a DMZ as well.

Comment: @ivanivan Would you mind linking me to some type of documentation or guide? Fairly new to this stuff and unsure what I would search in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically what you would do when wanting to connect to a service behind a single public IP (home or small office DSL or cable connection, etc) is bind the service to the private IP of the machine, and then configure your router to forward appropriate ports to the correct internal address and port (they can be different)

To help increase security, what is known as a DMZ can be used.  This essentially splits off another subnet of your internal network that can be forwarded to by the router and accessed by the rest of your network but machines/services on it can't initiate connections to your internal LAN.  This way if a service is hacked, the attacker can't use it as a bridge to your workstations, etc.

Unfortunately, the "How to do this" is dependent on what router you have, what version of software/firmware it is running, etc.  Use your favorite search engine and use terms like " port forwarding" or " DMZ" -  "RotoRouterv3.14 port forwarding"

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response.